# How to retrieve the luminance channel from an rgb image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, multidimensional-array, rgb, luminance

I'm trying to retrieve the luminance component of a set of 'tif' images in matlab.
The code is bellow:

```
function [defaultImages] = readImgLum(nFiles) 
% readImgLum reads a specified number of images in 'tif' format
% and retrieves the luminance component
narginchk(1, 1);
defaultImages = cell(nFiles, 1);                % store all images in a vector

for i = 1 : nFiles
    imagePreffix = int2str(i);
    imageFullName = strcat(imagePreffix, '.tif');
    image = imread(imageFullName);
    imageYCbCr = rgb2ycbcr(image);    
    defaultImages{i} = squeeze(imageYCbCr(:,:,1));
end
```

Am I correctly extracting the luminance component?

Comment: you can skip the `squeeze`.

Comment: There is no need for a squeeze I believe. Otherwise it looks fine to me.

Comment: As a check I would suggest to compare your output with the third channel of `rgb2hsv`.

Answer (score 3):

As the comments have stated, there is no need for `squeeze`.  This code also looks fine to me.  However, if you want to skip computing all components of `YCbCr` just to extract the luminance, use the SMPTE / PAL standard for calculating luminance instead.  This is actually done in `rgb2gray` in MATLAB if you want to look up the source.

In any case, assuming your images are unsigned 8-bit integer:

```
image = double(image); 
defaultImages{i} = uint8(0.299*image(:,:,1) + 0.587*image(:,:,2) + 0.114*image(:,:,3));
```

BTW, `image` is a built-in command in MATLAB.  It takes in any matrix, and visualizes it as an image in a new figure.  I highly suggest you use another variable to store your temporary image as you may be calling further code later on that requires `image` as a function.